# Internet explorer grab internal ip address

Tags: vbscript, javascript

I'm looking for a solution to grab people's internal ip addresses in IE (not using java or java applets). The equivalent in Java looks like that:

```
this.sock.bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress('0.0.0.0', 0));
this.sock.connect(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(document.domain, (!document.location.port)?80:document.location.port));
return this.sock.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
```

Is that something possible in vbscript or jscript? Could you provide me with an example?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Half duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)

Comment: Yes except this guy is looking into doing it with java. I'm looking for an alternative that works on IE without using applets.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get internal IP with JavaScript.

This looks like something you'll need an [ActiveX control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) for, *if* it is possible.

Comment: You can call java from javascript in FF, Chrome and Safari. Check this out: http://code.google.com/p/beef/source/browse/trunk/modules/beefjs/net/local.js

Answer (score 1):

I think that depending on the security settings in IE you might be able to use WMI. If so you could just use the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28VS.85%29.aspx) and it's `IPAddress` property.

The following sample in vbscript:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject( _ 
    "winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set IPConfigSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select IPAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration ")

For Each IPConfig in IPConfigSet
    If Not IsNull(IPConfig.IPAddress) Then 
        For i=LBound(IPConfig.IPAddress) _
            to UBound(IPConfig.IPAddress)
                WScript.Echo IPConfig.IPAddress(i)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Is taken from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394595%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN page.